# .net Custom MessageBox text is highlighted

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dialog, messagebox

Why?

I built a simple custom MessageBox as as a Dialog in C#. When I show the message boxvia Show(), the message text is not highlighted. When I show this messagebox vi ShowDialog(), the text *is* highlighted.

I don't want my text to be highlighted. Any thoughts or ideas?

```
public partial class MyMessageBox : Form
    {
        private String mCaption;
        private String mMessage;


        public MyMessageBox( Form anOwner, String aCaption, String aMessage )
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            mCaption = aCaption;
            Owner = anOwner;
            mMessage = aMessage;
        }


        private void btnCancelRequest_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            ( (AddressForm)Owner ).RequestCancelled();
        }


        private void btnOk_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            CloseDialog();
        }


        public void CloseDialog()
        {
            Close();
        }


        // Called from the Address Form
        public void HideCancelRequestButton()
        {
            btnCancelRequest.Visible = false;
        }


        private void MyMessageBox_Activated( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            Text = mCaption;
            txtMessage.Text = mMessage;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing from the Hungarian notation your message is displayed in a TextBox control named txtMessage. Why not replace this with a label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't see why the text would be highlighted, you could avoid this by explicitly specifying the textbox selection length:

```
txtMessage.SelectionLength = 0;
```

though as Jeremy commented, this may be a better use of a label unless you're actually expecting user input.

Comment: Yes, this answered my question perfectly. However, as mentioned by Jeremy and M. Babcock, I will be switching from a text box to a Label. Thank you gentlemen.